# Transforming list to map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to transform a list of strings:

```
def description = """user:some.mail@gmail.com;groups:Team-1, Team-2
user:some.othermail@gmail.com;groups:Team-2, Team-3
user:another.mail@gmail.com;groups:Team-1, Team-3
some other text"""

description = description.split('\\r\\n|\\n|\\r').findAll { it.startsWith('user') }
```

into a map so it looked like this:

```
[some.mail@gmail.com: "Team-2, Team-3", some.othermail@gmail.com: "Team-2, Team-3", another.mail@gmail.com: "Team-1, Team-3"]
```

so I could later iterate getting an e-mail address and corresponding teams.

Sadly with the below code I was only able to partly achieve it and only for one item of the list. I'm stuck with getting it into a loop and get the full result.

```
def userData = [:]
userData = description[0].split(';').inject([:]) { map, token ->
    token.split(':').with {
        map[it[0].trim()] = it[1].trim()
    }
    map
}
```

Can you give me a hint as for how I could get a map with all the items from the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collectEntries` method on a list:

```
def description = """user:some.mail@gmail.com;groups:Team-1, Team-2
user:some.othermail@gmail.com;groups:Team-2, Team-3
user:another.mail@gmail.com;groups:Team-1, Team-3
some other text"""

description = description.split('\\r\\n|\\n|\\r').findAll { it.startsWith('user') }

def map = description.collectEntries {
    // split "user:some.mail@gmail.com;groups:Team-1, Team-2"
    def split = it.split(';')
    // remove "user:" prefix
    def email = split[0].split(':')[1]
    // remove "groups:" prefix
    def groups = split[1].split(':')[1]
    // create a map entry
    [(email), groups]
}
```

Then running `map.forEach {k, v -> println "key: '${k}', value: '${v}'"}` prints following: (standard map to string may be a little bit chaotic in this case)

```
key: 'some.mail@gmail.com', value: 'Team-1, Team-2'
key: 'some.othermail@gmail.com', value: 'Team-2, Team-3'
key: 'another.mail@gmail.com', value: 'Team-1, Team-3'
```